# Dynamically change TableView Cell height

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

**Swift/Objective C - Simple Way to Dynamically change TableView Cell height**

In my table view cell break first line and third line, every label will dynamic

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Comment: This answer have each and every step mention by images and it is easy to understand every one.....

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Add Constraints to Image View (top, Leading, trailing, Height)**

**Don't Add Bottom Constraints**

[image]

**Add Constraints to Each label (top, Leading, trailing, Bottom)**

[image]

**Add Constraints to last label (top, Leading, trailing, Bottom)**

[image]

**Set each label**

Number of Line = **0**

Line Breaks mode = **word warp**

[image]

**Table View Datasource and Delegate Methods**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PropertyListCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell!

    imgProperty = viewBg.viewWithTag(111) as! RemoteImageView
    lblPropertyName = viewBg.viewWithTag(112) as! UILabel
    lblPrice = viewBg.viewWithTag(113) as! UILabel
    lblAddress = viewBg.viewWithTag(114) as! UILabel
    lblAreaPerSquare = viewBg.viewWithTag(115) as! UILabel

    imgProperty.imageURL = NSURL(string: "Image Url")
    lblPropertyName.text="Jai Maharashtra Apartment"
    lblPrice.text="Rs. 900 - 10000"
    lblAddress.text="411041,Maharashtra Sadan, Pune, Maharashtra , India" // just address changed. 
    lblAreaPerSquare.text="500 Square Meter"

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 44.0
}
```

Now All labels are **Dynamic**

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer, indeed! Congrats. :-)

Comment: Thanx bro for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift - 3.0**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     var height:CGFloat = CGFloat()
     if indexPath.row == 0 {
     height = 80
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1 {
     height = self.view.frame.size.height - 80 - 44 - 64
     print(height)
    }
    return height
   }
```