# Dynamic Table View Cell & Content Size conflicting & Pintrest Layout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

In my requirement currently,I wanted to develop a Pintrest layout view. For that ***I have 2 tableView's on same ScrollView***.

**mark:** I didn't use collectionView as it was very difficult to customize the flow Layout for this purpose &  I do not want to include a 3rd Party framework for the same.

Check the attached screenshot -

[image]

I am ***populating them with 2 arrays one for even & one for odd items***. 
I am making these ***tableView's non scrollable*** & ***increasing my scrollView's contentView's height as per the tallest tableView***. Both the ***tableView's have custom cells with dynamically increasing contents*** i.e a label.

**in my viewDidLoad()**

```
self.tableViewCol1.estimatedRowHeight = 296
        self.tableViewCol1.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableViewCol1.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None

        self.tableViewCol2.estimatedRowHeight = 296
        self.tableViewCol2.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableViewCol2.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
```

**in my DataSource method -**

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {
            var cell2 = MostLikedTVCscnd()//custom Cell for 2nd Table
            var cell1 = MostLikedTVC()//custom Cell for 1st Table

            if tableView == tableViewCol1
            {
                let cell = tableViewCol1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MostLikedTVC
                cell.imageCol1.image = imageArr1[indexPath.row] as? UIImage
                cell.aboutLblCol1.text = labelArr1[indexPath.row] as? String//dynamic increasing label
                cell1=cell
            }
            else if tableView == tableViewCol2
            {
                let cell = tableViewCol2.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MostLikedTVCscnd
                cell.imageCol2.image = imageArr2[indexPath.row] as? UIImage
                cell.aboutLblCol2.text = labelArr2[indexPath.row] as? String
                cell2 = cell
            }

//changing the height constraint of table's to make the table view non scrollable
           tableView1HghtCnstrnt.constant = tableViewCol1.contentSize.height
           tableView2HghtCnstrnt.constant = tableViewCol2.contentSize.height

     //comparing the content size of table's to check which table is the tallest & adjust the height of the main ScrollView's content       
            if tableViewCol1.contentSize.height>tableViewCol2.contentSize.height
            {
                mainViewHghtCnstrnt.constant = tableViewCol1.contentSize.height+35//mainViewHghtCnstrnt :- mainScrollView's content height constraint & 35 is the padding
            }
            else if tableViewCol1.contentSize.height<tableViewCol2.contentSize.height
            {
                mainViewHghtCnstrnt.constant = tableViewCol2.contentSize.height+35
            }
            else if tableViewCol1.contentSize.height==tableViewCol2.contentSize.height
            {
                mainViewHghtCnstrnt.constant = tableViewCol2.contentSize.height+35
            }

//returning the cell
            if tableView == tableViewCol1
            {
                return cell1

            }
            else
            {
                return cell2

            }

        }

    }
```

But my problem is that the table's are not properly calculating the size of their content's. I did some search and here an answer to a question says - ***contentSize will be messed up when you give estimatedRowHeight***

**So what options do I have? What can be done to realise the same properly?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789560/dynamically-change-tableview-cell-height-swift/35789561#35789561

Comment: @ShrikantTanwade My cells are increasing size but my calculation of tableView's content size is not giving proper results

Comment: Why your using two tables ?

Comment: You can try two section In first section load MostLikedTVCscnd cell and In second cell load MostLikedTVC cell

Comment: @ShrikantTanwade Can you please check my updated question & attached screenshot

Comment: because table view use reuse cell  to fit visible cell with limit of table view size -> so to display full table with all cell you need compute table content size.height = total cell height + margin , padding + section header height, table view header height.... and set table view frame = content size.

Comment: @sticker Can you post that as an answer with a bit elaborated code? And how can I calculate cell height when cell is dynamic in nature with a variable size label?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tableView's contentSize property to get the height required for the tableView.

I have done a demo to test this, and it is working as you are expecting.

[image]

My constraint are as follows:

> 1. ScrollView:
>
> LeadingSpace to SuperView, TrailingSpace to SuperView, TopSpace to
>   SuperView, BottomSpace to SuperView
>
> 2. ContainerView (UIView inside scrollView):
>
> LeadingSpace to SuperView, TrailingSpace to SuperView, TopSpace to
>   SuperView, BottomSpace to SuperView, EqualWidth to SuperView (i.e
>   scrollView)
>
> 3. ATableView
>
> LeadingSpace to SuperView, TrailingSpace to BTableView, TopSpace to
>   SuperView, Width fixed points, HeightFixed points (Created outlet of
>   this constraint), BottomSpace to SuperView with StandardSpacing and
>   LowPriority (250)
>
> 4. BTableView
>
> LeadingSpace to ATableView, TrailingSpace to SuperView, TopSpace to
>   SuperView, Width fixed points, HeightFixed points (Created outlet of
>   this constraint), BottomSpace to SuperView with StandardSpacing and
>   LowPriority (250)

And here is my full code,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableViewA: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewB: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraintBTableView: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraintATableView: NSLayoutConstraint!

var tableViewACellCount = 50
var tableViewBCellCound = 20

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Dont set estimatedRowHeight as it is displaying empty cell at the bottom of tableView (try playing with this uncomment estimatedRowHeight)

    //tableViewA.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    tableViewA.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    //tableViewB.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    tableViewB.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    //Try both methods
    self.performSelector("adjustTableViewHeight", withObject: [], afterDelay: 0.0)
    //self.adjustTableViewHeight()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if(tableView.isEqual(tableViewA)) { //A TableView
        return tableViewACellCount
    } else { //B TableView
       return tableViewBCellCound
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")

    return cell!
}

func adjustTableViewHeight() {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        self.tableViewA.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.tableViewB.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    heightConstraintATableView.constant = tableViewA.contentSize.height
    heightConstraintBTableView.constant = tableViewB.contentSize.height
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry it isn't working. Your demo might be as cells are not dynamic in nature